# How to change a UI's color when its being hovered over

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a UI that changes to a lighter color when its hovered over (roblox's default is darker)

MouseEnter and MouseLeave have already been tested and don't work the way I want it to. MouseEnter keeps the darkening and makes my target color darker than it should be.

Is this possible, if so, how would it be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MouseEnter and MouseLeave will work, you just need to disable your button's [AutoButtonColor](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/GuiButton/AutoButtonColor) property.
From the docs :

> The AutoButtonColor determines whether the button automatically changes color when the user’s Mouse hovers over or clicks on it.
>
> If true, the button will automatically change color when the mouse hovers over or clicks on it. If false, the button will not change.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying continuously to search for this but couldn't find anything.